# ngClass binding isn't updating in real time

Tags: angular, binding, real-time

Hello I am new to angluar, I made a toggle modal window(side nav)

```
  <mat-toolbar
    [ngClass]="rosterService.getBGColour(currentShift)">
    <mat-toolbar-row class="w-full relative flex justify-between">
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

this is getBGColour in roster.service

```
  getBGColour(shift) {
    let val = 0;
    const vals = [];
    if (shift?.uuid) {
      shift.tasks.forEach((task) => {
        vals.push(task.supplier.release_status);
        vals.push(task.resource.release_status);
      });
      if (shift.release_status > 0 && vals.includes(3)) {
        val = 3;
      } else if (shift.release_status > 0 && (vals.includes(1) || vals.includes(undefined) || vals.includes(0))) {
        val = 1;
      } else if (shift.release_status === 0) {
        val = 0;
      } else {
        val = 2;
      }
    }

    return this.releaseStatus[val].colour;
  }
```

and this is the main view

```
  <mat-drawer
    class="w-3/5 dark:bg-primary"
    data-cy="creating-shift-drawer"
    [autoFocus]="false"
    [mode]="'over'"
    [position]="'end'"
    #matDrawerAddShift>
    <app-add-shift
      *ngIf="viewAddShift && matDrawerAddShift.opened"
      [viewMode]="viewMode"
      [addShiftData]="addShiftData"
      (closeSideBar)="closeSideNav('add')">
    </app-add-shift>
  </mat-drawer>
```

when user accept the request, it shows a certain color, it works well but the problem is
I need to close the modal and open it again to see the change.
I thought if I use binding like that, [ngClass]="method()", the view will be updated automatically, but it is not. I searched on google and chatGPT, I tried changeDetectorRef, subscribe to the Roster.currentShift
could you please tell me how to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Where do you get shifts from, a subscription? Does it get updated by user's action that should change the colour? Try logging the result of val before you return it in service. You'll also see it's logged a lot of times (because your method is called on each DOM check, but we'll get there).

Answer (score 0):

Use change detector ref to manually detect the change.

```
getBGColour(shift) {
this.cd.detectChanges();
let val = 0;
const vals = [];
.
.
```

Dont forget to inject ChangeDetectorRef in constructor